# prove $ E $ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ (X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $μ^∗$ be the outer measure generated by $μ$. prove $\mu(A)=\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\cap E^C)$ holds for all $A\in S$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$. that is $E$ is measurable with respect to $\mu^*$. thanks

Comment: What is the set E?

Comment: @FBD: $ E $ is a subset of $ X$.

Comment: Is this proof correct? $\mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^C) = \mu^*(A \cap (E \cup E^C)) = \mu^*(A \cap X) = \mu^*(A)$.

Comment: @noether: I think it is correct. thanks noether.

Comment: I will write it down as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a quick answer

$\mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^C) = \mu^*(A \cap (E \cup E^C)) = \mu^*(A \cap X) = \mu^*(A) = \mu(A)$.